# Using "signed" INT in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, integer, int, signed

How do you insert a SIGNED "int" into a MySQL table, so that I can get a longer range?

I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 6):

If it's not `UNSIGNED`, then it's `SIGNED`. Either way the range is the same size. If you want a bigger range than `INT` allows, use `BIGINT`.

Comment: This ^^.  Longer ranges are only increased by higher capacity data types which will result in larger storage per row. BIGINT is the appropriate next largest datatype past INT.

Answer (score 2):

The range of a signed TINYINT is -128 to +127. If it is unsigned, the range is 0 to +255. In both cases the tinyint provides room for 256 different values. If you use the column as an auto-increment column, you should use unsigned numbers. That effectively doubles your range, because auto-increment columns do not get a negative value (unless you set it explicitly).